# Postgresql fails on startup: "FATAL: postmaster became multithreaded during startup"

Tags: postgresql

Trying to start PostgreSQL, but get the following error:

```
$ pg_ctl -D postgres_data start
server starting
FATAL:  postmaster became multithreaded during startup
HINT:  Set the LC_ALL environment variable to a valid locale
```

My locale is set:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL="C"
```

System is MacOS 10.10.5, PostgreSQL version is 9.5.0.

I followed Michael's suggestion.  Now the locale values are:

```
$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

But the error remains.

I Googled the error message to see if anyone had run into this problem, but did not see a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your locale is mis-set.

You have `LANG` defined as `en_US.UTF-8`, but everything else is defined as `C`. These are *rather different*, and mixing them will cause all sorts of weirdness.

Do what the error message told you: set `LC_ALL` to the correct locale (and set all the rest of them too).

Comment: I know little about locales. Is the correct locale "en_US.UTF-8"?  Note that I didn't explicitly set any of those variables - that is what MacOS did.  It has a "Language and Region" system preference which apparently does not set the LC_* stuff.

Comment: That depends. Do you speak English and are in the US?

Comment: Yes - the LANG is correct.

Comment: When I run `locale` on El Capitan, they are all set correctly. If you need help with setting these, you should do so elsewhere, such as [su] or [apple.se]. That really isn't on topic here.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue for My Mac running Postgres 9.5 and 9.6 by setting LC_ALL for the 'postgres' account.

See details on https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/317#issuecomment-251786830

Comment: Where is the 'postgres' account located?